# ES6 module Import giving "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier"

Tags: javascript, html, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

For a personal project, I'm trying to use ES6 import to write cleaner code. As first test, I'm writing an object that should generate a menu. The whole code is working when I'm directly loading up the class, yet when using the import and export in ES6, it gives an "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier" error on the `import` line in `main.js`

I've got the following files:

**assets/js/menu.module.js**

```
'use strict';

export default class Menu
{ ... }
```

**assets/js/main.js**

```
import Menu from "./menu.module.js";

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    const menu = new Menu();
});
```

**index.html**

```
<script type="module" src="assets/js/menu.module.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/main.js">
```

Note that these are only the relevant lines of code.

Using the `<script type="module">` line or not did not seem to make any difference for me. I do have both the chrome flags for experimental and ES6 Modules enabled, as without them I received an error about `import` not being defined.

Chrome version would be 62, so according to different sources (including google's update log itself) this should be working, even without the flags.

Can anyone enlighten me as of why this is not working, and what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Is there an associated line number? Which file is the error in?

Comment: @BoyWithSilverWings forgot to add that, Just added now. It's on the `import` line in `main.js`

Comment: Shouldn't `main.js` need `type="module"` as well? It uses module syntax, after all.

Comment: Your `window.addEventListener(` call is missing a closing parenthesis

Comment: What if you are not using HTML?

Comment: @VapporWashmade That sounds like a separate issue as mine originally was about ES6 modules in the browser. Have you posted it as a separate question? As without any more context it's rather impossible to nail down the issue.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

As @Bergi mentioned in the comment, adding `type="module"` to the `main.js` import line in the HTML solved the issue. All is working now. I.e.

```
<script type="module" src="assets/js/main.js">
```

Thanks to all of you who responded and tried to help.

Comment: In a previous comment you said adding the semicolon fixed it. Now you're saying adding the type fixed it.

Comment: @TomRussell Which comment? Because I'm unable to locate it. The issue for me was with the `type="module"` thing.

Comment: Where? Which comment? What's the solution?

Comment: @bernard @Pithikos You have to add `type='module'` to the Main script as well. That's exactly what the answer you left your comment on described. This one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47633417/4327948

Comment: where would one add `type="module"` in the file?

Comment: Super unclear, but I believe the idea is to add `type="module"` to the script tag which is importing the `main.js` file as well as the script tag which is importing the module @ChumiestBucket

Comment: I had the same problem and the solution works! But why should a consumer of a module be defined as `type="module"` !?

Comment: Note, this also solved the error I was receiving, "Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module".  I think it worth noting in the event others see that error instead of the one referenced in the original post.

Answer (score 4):

From what I can see you are trying to load the file `menu.module.js` while it's actually named `menu.js`.

PS: From what I recall you could also drop the `.js` from the import statement.

Comment: I had a similar situation, but am using php to inject a script. I'm only using vanilla javascript and I needed to put the ".js" extension on my import for it to work. I know with React the .js extension is not needed, but I'm guessing that's going to vary based on what environment you're working in. Hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 1):

you can use any module bundler, one of the simple flexible solutions is `parcel 2`, it's beta right now but you can play with it.

```
 - npm i -D parcel@next
 - parcel index.html
```