# 'Unexpected identifier' when trying to import modules in Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, module

I'm developing a Chrome extension that will make use of some background scripts. I thought it would be interesting to make use of modules since Google recently added native support for them.

However, I'm getting a 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier' error when I'm attemtping to import a module. The errors points to the line of code where the import is written. Here's an example:

In main.js:

```
import test from './test.js';
```

In test.js:

```
export default function test () {
  console.log('this is a test.');
}
```

I've tried various other formats, but none of them works. Interestingly, Chrome's newest import('file.js') function works just fine. However, I'm looking for a way to import modules without using promises.

Am I doing something wrong, or am I just not supposed to make use of modules in Chrome Extensions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ES6 module Import giving "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47632562/es6-module-import-giving-uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-identifier)

Answer (score 9):

If you are getting an error shown below while using import (ES6 module). 
[image]

You need to inform the browser by using the **`type="module"`** in the script tag you are using in the HTML file. Use this to link you js file in HTML

`<script type="module" src="./main.js"></script>`

Answer (score 0):

You should add `type='module'` to the `main.js` import line

look at this [ES6 module Import giving "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47632562/es6-module-import-giving-uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-identifier)

Answer (score 0):

Manifest V2 Chrome extensions do not natively support ES modules. In order to use them in a Manifest V2 extension, you’ll need to use a bundler like Webpack.

Manifest V3 Chrome extensions have support for ES modules in background service workers. The [Chrome documentation explains how to enable ES modules](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/service_workers/#manifest) by adding a field to `manifest.json`:

> You can optionally specify an extra field of `"type": "module"` to include the service worker as an ES Module, which allows you to `import` further code. See [ES modules in service workers](https://web.dev/es-modules-in-sw/) for more information. For example:
>
> ```json
>   "background": {
>     "service_worker": "background.js",
>     "type": "module"
>   }
> ```

[ES modules are supported in service workers since Chrome 91](https://chromestatus.com/feature/4609574738853888), though I’m not sure if they were introduced for Manifest V3 service workers at the same time.