# Long load using ES6 modules in Chrome

Tags: javascript, es6-modules, es6-class

My javascript app is for a kiosk and is only targeting the Chrome browser. I'm using Chrome version 65. I am trying to use ES6 modules without using a transpiler like Babel. My code was originally:

in index.html:

```
<script src="js/index.js"></script>
```

index.js:

```
import Main from './classes/Main.js';

const init = () => {
  const app = new Main();
};

init();
```

Main.js:

```
export default class Main {
  constructor() {
  }
}
```

Originally I got the error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier" from index.js line 1. Then based on [ES6 module Import giving "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47632562/es6-module-import-giving-uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-identifier?rq=1) I added 'type="module"' to the html tag:

```
<script type="module" src="js/index.js"></script>
```

This did load, but it takes my browser about 15 seconds to load index.js and main.js according to the network profiler. What could be going on?

Answer (score 1):

So I ran some tests on my local box. I have a simple NodeJs server running with the following three files:

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>es6 Module test</title>
  <script>
  console.time('load module');
  console.time('time until constructor called');
  </script>
  <script type="module" src="module.js"></script>
  <script>
  console.timeEnd('load module');
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  See console output.
</body>
</html>
```

**module.js**

```
import Main from './Main.js';

const init = () => {
  const app = new Main();
};

init();
```

and

**Main.js**

```
export default class Main {
  constructor() {
    console.timeEnd('time until constructor called');
  }
}
```

Running this code in Chrome 65 (On a Mac)

I get the following output:

**Run 1**

```
load module: 0.141845703125ms
time until constructor called: 7.90087890625ms
```

**Run 2**

```
load module: 0.139892578125ms
time until constructor called: 6.5498046875ms
```

**Run 3**

```
load module: 0.160888671875ms
time until constructor called: 7.14404296875ms
```

**Run 4**

```
load module: 0.297119140625ms
time until constructor called: 7.4228515625ms
```

> My download times ranged between 2ms and 10ms for each of the three files.

I really can't tell why your times are so much slower. But they should not be. Maybe your server is getting hammered and unable to respond fast enough?

**Possible things to check:**

What happens if you try to download each of the files from the address bar? Do they still take forever to download?

What about on a different server?

Comment: These are good suggestions. I'll give them a try and report back.

Answer (score 1):

I was was having the same problem when serving my files using:

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer
```

After changing to use python3 `http.server` instead it fixed the problem:

```
python3 -m http.server
```

Comment: Great! weird error though. I switched to serve with npx and all works fine

Comment: This did not resolve the issue for me. In fact it made it worse (running via WSL on Windows 10) by spreading it to HTML files. :\