# Importing node.js module - SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to do the following import

```
import  ResClient from 'resclient';
```

#### Result

```
/home/arran/WebstormProjects/untitled1/app.js:2
import  ResClient from 'resclient';
        ^^^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at new Script (vm.js:85:7)
    at createScript (vm.js:266:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:314:10)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:698:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js 
(internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:749:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:630:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:570:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:562:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:801:12)
```

- The module documentation is located [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/resclient) and does the exact same import in the example.
- I have installed the module globally.

  ```
  npm list -g | grep resclient
  └─┬ resclient@2.0.2
  ```
- I am using the following node version

  ```
   $node -v
   v11.10.1
  ```

I have seen some other posts about this error. For example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47632562/es6-module-import-giving-uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-identifier) but it is a browser based problem using client side javascript rather than node. 
I'm a node newbie, so would appreciate any pointers no matter how basic.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I use an es6 import in node?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45854169/how-can-i-use-an-es6-import-in-node)

Comment: @Seblor I disagree. I have seen that post. imports only work natively with node.js after version 8.50. I have upgraded my version to 11.1, so that is no longer an issue for me. If you look at the error they are talking about it is different

Comment: @ArranDuff I'm afraid you're only partially correct, it is supported in Node 8.5+ but only with the `--experimental-modules` flag enabled (which the answer linked does explain). So your options are to either enable that flag or use a transpiler like Babel.

Comment: Ok, fair enough looks like I misread the post. Thanks guys

Answer (score 5):

As for node 12, you can add the property `type` in your package.json as

`"type": "module"`

and dont forget to run node with experimental-modules flag `node --experimental-modules youapp.js`

Comment: `"type": "module"` Good catch

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same issue. Here is how I fixed it. 
I first updated my node and its package manager version using the following commands :

```
npm install node@latest -g
```

and

```
npm install npm@latest -g
```

After doing so, I went to my `package.json` file and added the following line before the `scripts` property:

```
"type": "module",
```

And last, I went back and tried to run my code using `node app.js` but it did not work until I used the following command:

```
node --experimental-modules app.js
```

At your side, replace `app.js` with your **index file**. Hope it also works for you

Nice coding