# What else need to import module in Node?

Tags: node.js, express, npm, yarnpkg

I try to use `express` in my application.

```
import express from 'express';
```

So I added it to package.json.

```
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-graphql": "^0.9.0",
```

Executed `yarn`.
But still I get an error when starting yarn. Do you know why?

[image: <code>enter image description here</code>]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Importing node.js module - SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55002755/importing-node-js-module-syntaxerror-unexpected-identifier)

Comment: either switch to `const express = require('express')` or read the above article to setup a compilation step

Answer (score 0):

const express = require('express');

Answer (score 0):

The reason it doesn't work is Node doesn't support ES6 imports yet. [This link](https://timonweb.com/tutorials/how-to-enable-ecmascript-6-imports-in-nodejs/) discribes how to enable imports for Node. Another recommendation would be to use require.

```
const express = require('express');
```