# cropper.js - unexpected identifier

Tags: javascript, cropper

trying to use `cropper.js`:

https://github.com/fengyuanchen/cropperjs
https://fengyuanchen.github.io/cropperjs/

After downloading and unpacking files I created `index.php` on the root level:

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<title>IMGED</title>
<meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0'>
<link href="src/index.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
<div>
  <img id="image" src="img.jpg" alt='img'>
</div>
<script src="src/index.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Console:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier... index.js:1
```

index.js

```
import Cropper from './js/cropper';
export default Cropper;
```

What is wrong, pls?

Comment: In reading [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47632562/es6-module-import-giving-uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-identifier), perhaps try adding `type="module"` to your `<script>`

Comment: @TylerRoper, tried and getting this - `http://localhost/imgedit/02/src/js/cropper net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)`